# How to delete all highlights from a highlight graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

Suppose that I have a graph with highlight and some other options:

```
HighlightGraph[Graph[{1<->2,2<->3,3<->1},VertexLabels->"Name"],{Style[1<->2,Blue],3}]
```

And Now I want to remove all highlight and transform it back to

```
Graph[{1<->2,2<->3,3<->1},VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

or equivalent form.

We can see from `FullForm` of the highlighted graph that the highlight options are specially stored in the rules `GraphHighlight` and `GraphHighlightStyle`, so it should be easy to delete these options.

But I tired `SetProperty`, it won't work that easily, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, GraphHighlight -> False] &, g, 
 PropertyValue[g, GraphHighlight]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PropertyValue[{g, #}, GraphHighlight] =. & /@ PropertyValue[g, GraphHighlight]; 
g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Fold[RemoveProperty[{##}, GraphHighlight] &, #, PropertyValue[#, GraphHighlight]] &@g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]